Maximum gradient norm of 3d triangle by varying z values by +/- delta
I have a triangle in a 3d space composed of the non-collinear points: $ (x_1,y_1,z_1+\epsilon_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2+\epsilon_2), (x_3,y_3,z_3+\epsilon_3)$.
The $x,y,z$ components are fixed but the $\epsilon$ component belong to $[-\Delta,+\Delta]$.
Let $A(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3), B(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3), C(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3)$ be such that the equation of the plane defined by the triangle is: $z = A(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3) x + B(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3) y + C(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3)$
My question is: what is the value of $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3)$ that maximizes $A^2 + B^2$?
First, I have a strong intuition (and plenty of computational results) that the solution has the form $\epsilon_i = ±\Delta, \forall i$, but I am struggling to prove it mathematically.
Second, can we derive a rule from the values of $x_i,y_i,z_i$ that would indicate which sign should be each $\epsilon_i$.
Thank you for your help on this.

I realized that this question is equivalent to another one that I posted at the link below and for which I had an answer.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4934390/maximum-of-elliptic-paraboloid-on-a-convex-polygonal-domain
